# Change class range on children when parent div contains specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, foreach, parseint

I need help adding and removing classes on child divs based on an existing class on a parent div.

I already have a working example:

```js
(function(d) {
  const galleryCarousel = document.querySelectorAll(".summary-item-list");
  const carouselSlidesFourParent = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-4");
  const carouselSlidesThreeParent = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-3");
  const carouselSlidesTwoParent = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-2");
  const carouselSlidesFour = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-4 .summary-item");
  const carouselSlidesThree = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-3 .summary-item");
  const carouselSlidesTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-2 .summary-item");

  carouselSlidesFour.forEach((element, x) => {
    const a = parseInt(x / 4) + 1;
    element.classList.add(`summary-item-${a}`);
  });

  carouselSlidesThree.forEach((element, y) => {
    const b = parseInt(y / 3) + 1;
    element.classList.add(`summary-item-${b}`);
  });

  carouselSlidesTwo.forEach((element, z) => {
    const c = parseInt(z / 2) + 1;
    element.classList.add(`summary-item-${c}`);
  });
}(document));
```

```css
.sqs-block-summary {
  border: solid 2px #000000;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sqs-block-content {
  margin: 10px;
}

.summary-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25.25%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

.sqs-block-summary * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.summary-item-list-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.summary-item-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  vertical-align: top;
}

.summary-item-1 {
  color: red !important;
}

.summary-item-2 {
  color: green !important;
}

.summary-item-3 {
  color: blue !important;
}

.summary-item-4 {
  color: orange !important;
}

.summary-item-5 {
  color: grey !important;
}

.summary-item-6 {
  color: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sqs-block-summary four-row">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <div class="summary-block-wrapper">
      <div class="summary-item-list-container">
        <div class="summary-item-list sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-4">
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 1 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 2 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 3 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 4 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 5 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 6 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 7 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 8 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 9 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 10 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 11 </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sqs-block-summary three-row">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <div class="summary-block-wrapper">
      <div class="summary-item-list-container">
        <div class="summary-item-list sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-3">
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 1 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 2 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 3 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 4 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 5 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 6 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 7 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 8 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 9 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 10 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 11 </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sqs-block-summary three-row">
  <div class="sqs-block-content">
    <div class="summary-block-wrapper">
      <div class="summary-item-list-container">
        <div class="summary-item-list sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-2">
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 1 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 2 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 3 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 4 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 5 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 6 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 7 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 8 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 9 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 10 </div>
          <div class="summary-item"> Item 11 </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I need help with dynamically adding/removing the class ".summary-item-_" on each number of child divs when the parent div class changes ".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-4, .sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-3, .sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-2". The parent classes change on screen size.

This is what I'm working on but with no success:

```js
(function(d) {
  const galleryCarousel = document.querySelectorAll(".summary-item-list");
  const carouselSlidesFourParent = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-4");
  const carouselSlidesThreeParent = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-3");
  const carouselSlidesTwoParent = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-2");
  const carouselSlidesFour = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-4 .summary-item");
  const carouselSlidesThree = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-3 .summary-item");
  const carouselSlidesTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".sqs-gallery-design-carousel-slides-in-view-2 .summary-item");

  carouselSlidesFour.forEach((element, x) => {
    const a = parseInt(x / 4) + 1;
    
    if (hasClass(galleryCarousel, carouselSlidesFourParent)) {
      element.classList.add(`summary-item-${a}`);
    } 
    else {
      element.classList.remove(`summary-item-${a}`);
    }
  });

  carouselSlidesThree.forEach((element, y) => {
    const b = parseInt(y / 3) + 1;
    
    if (hasClass(galleryCarousel, carouselSlidesThreeParent)) {
      element.classList.add(`summary-item-${b}`);
    } 
    else {
      element.classList.remove(`summary-item-${b}`);
    }
  });

  carouselSlidesTwo.forEach((element, z) => {
    const c = parseInt(z / 2) + 1;
    
    if (hasClass(galleryCarousel, carouselSlidesTwoParent)) {
      element.classList.add(`summary-item-${c}`);
    } 
    else {
      element.classList.remove(`summary-item-${c}`);
    }
  });
}(document));
```

Comment: You try to check for a class with the function ``hasClass()`` and give a collection of elements to that function instead a string with the class names. Furthermore the function has to be appended to an element. And last: it's a jQuery function, which doesn't work with plain JavaScript...